# Timing Error for Windows OnScreen Keyboard when adding wait command with pywinauto

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, keyboard

When opening windows onscreen keyboard and adding a wait command i automatically get  TimeoutError: timedout

I tried removing the wait command and it did work but I want to figure out why it's causing the error when adding the wait command.

```py
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application().start('osk.exe')
app.OSK.wait('ready', timeout=30)



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/py/32/SP9A.py", line 33, in <module>
    window.wait('visible', timeout=6)

  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 512, in wait lambda: self.__check_all_conditions(check_method_names, retry_interval))

  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 375, in wait_until raise err

pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError: timed out

getting timedout error
```

Comment: How `window` object was declared? The information above is sufficient to say only that described window is not found or not visible during 6 seconds. But how this window is described? Please figure out the context to improve the question quality.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I re-edited my post. Apologies on the vagueness.

Comment: What `print([w.window_text() for w in app.windows()])` prints after some pause? Is it the same as for `Application(backend="uia")`?